# Rmarkdown : exporting table1 descriptive statistics through shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am working on a shiny app which takes user datas in input and complete first classical descriptive statistics and then a full statistical analysis. Indeed, the descriptive statistic part is done with table1 package [table1 documentation used](https://benjaminrich.github.io/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html#displaying-different-statistics-for-different-variables). At the end of the app I want to allow the user to download a full report containing all the plot and tables (especially descriptive statistic tables).

I am able to write some Rmarkdown scripts to include ggplots and DT datatables in the report. The problem is about the table1 object.

I render them using renderUI in the server part and uiOutput in the ui part.

Here is the code used :

**Shiny script**

```
library(shiny)
library(sas7bdat)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(factoextra)
library(FactoMineR)
library(corrplot)
library(cluster)
library(NbClust)
library(clValid)
library(dendextend)
library(summarytools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(table1)

options(shiny.maxRequestSize=30*1024^2)
ui <-fluidPage(

  navlistPanel(

    #Welcome Page with logo and explanations 

    tabPanel("Welcome",textOutput("welcome_message"),textOutput("welcome_message_2"),img(src="logo_danone.jpg", height = 350, width = 350)),

    #Selector for file upload

    tabPanel("Input Datas",fileInput('datafile_LB', 'Choose LB Database file',
                                     accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
             fileInput('datafile_DS', 'Choose DS Database file',accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
             fileInput('datafile_VS', 'Choose VS Database file',accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
             fileInput('datafile_SV', 'Choose SV Database file',accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain')),
             fileInput('datafile_DM', 'Choose DM Database file',accept=c('text/csv', 'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain'))),


    # Display of the input data without any modification

    tabPanel("Raw Datas",
             DT::dataTableOutput("filetable_LB"), radioButtons('format', 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                                                               inline = TRUE), downloadButton('downloadReport')



  ),
  tabPanel("test plot", plotOutput("graph")),
  tabPanel("Disposition of subjects", uiOutput("disposition"))
))

##### Server part #####

server <- function(input, output, session ) {

  # Seting directory and import dependent functions



  ##### Input Loading #####

  filedata_LB <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile_LB
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.sas7bdat(infile$datapath)
  })

  filedata_DS <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datafile_DS
    if (is.null(infile)) {
      # User has not uploaded a file yet
      return(NULL)
    }
    read.sas7bdat(infile$datapath)
  })

  tableau <- reactive({table1(~ DSDECOD, data= filedata_DS(), topclass="Rtable1-zebra")})




  #######################################################################################################################
  #################################                                                     #################################
  #################################         Primary Endpoint Output                     #################################
  #################################                                                     #################################
  #######################################################################################################################


  #This previews the CSV data file

  output$filetable_LB <- DT::renderDataTable({DT::datatable(filedata_LB())})

  output$graph <- renderPlot({ggplot(data = filedata_LB(), aes(y = LBSTRESN)) + geom_boxplot()})

  output$disposition <- renderUI(print(table1(~ DSDECOD, data= filedata_DS(), topclass="Rtable1-zebra")))

  output$downloadReport <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste('my-report', sep = '.', switch(
        input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
      ))
    },

    content = function(file) {
      src <- "C:/Users/graditse/Desktop/test_markdown/report_file.Rmd"

      # temporarily switch to the temp dir, in case you do not have write
      # permission to the current working directory
      owd <- setwd(tempdir())
      on.exit(setwd(owd))
      file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)

      library(rmarkdown)
      out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
        input$format,
        PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
      ))
      file.rename(out, file)
    }
  )


}





shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Rmd script**

````
    ---
title: "test"
author: "seb"
date: "26 juin 2019"
output: html_document
always_allow_html: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.


```{r, fig.align='center', fig.pos='htb!', echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
library(DT)
library(webshot)
datatable(filedata_LB(),rownames=FALSE, options = list(dom='t',ordering=F))
```
```{r, echo=FALSE}
# library(ggplot2)
#  p <-  ggplot(data = filedata_LB(), aes(y = LBSTRESN)) + geom_boxplot()
#  p

output$graph

```

```{r, echo=False}
library(webshot)
library(table1)
library(shiny)
 reactive(table1(~ DSDECOD, data= filedata_DS(), topclass="Rtable1-zebra", output = "markdown"))


```
````

When I try to download the report, this can't be done I got  :

> Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.
>     [No stack trace available]

I don't really know how to handle this problem. This is strange because the DT table is also reactive and can be displayed into the report.

Is there a solution to display readable descriptive statistic tables into the Shiny app and in the report ?

I used the table1 package beacause it offers th possibility to process continuous and discrete variables, on different groups.

Thanks in advance !